# Быстрая конкатенация строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Как быстро объединять в `python` строки? Подскажите реализацию. Я поискал несколько [ссылок](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316887/what-is-the-most-efficient-string-concatenation-method-in-python#:%7E:text=In%20Python%202.6%2C%20the%20plus,always%20faster%20on%20Python%203.), а также сделал несколько моих. Но, видимо, самое быстрое -- это `join`. Есть ли что-то быстрее? Кажется, что за счёт алгоритмов (например, за счёт группировки строк) здесь не выгирать и нужны знания об устройстве аллокации памяти.

```
import datetime
import random
import string


def get_random_string(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(length))
    return result_str


def f1(x):
    return ','.join(x)


def f2(x):
    template = ','.join(['{}' for _ in range(len(x))])
    return template.format(*x)


total = 0
for j in range(1000):
    x = [get_random_string(random.randint(1, 30)) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 30))]
    for i in range(100):
        t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
        f2(x)
        total += (datetime.datetime.now() - t0).total_seconds()
print(total)
```

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Для частного случая с "," может подойти и такое: `f"{*list,}"`, но здесь будут оставаться кортежные скобки.

Comment: @strawdog попробую. Их можно убрать

Comment: @strawdog Ваш метод неэффективен. Он примерно как `f2`

Comment: простите, а старое доброе str1+str2 не подойдёт ?

Comment: @Интик инкрементально, один за одним, кажется, точно дольше будет, так как разом объединить быстрее, чем каждый раз память перевыделять.

Comment: def f3(x):
    z=''
    for i in x:
        z+=i
    return z   результат (0.2) в 2 раза хуже f1(0.1) и в 2 раза лучше f2(0.4)

Comment: кстати. быстрее всего будет вставить кусок кода из си.

Comment: еще, конечно, можно попробовать передавать не список, а кортеж и поиграться с lru_cache, но не думаю, что это сильно поможет